# WebStorm 11 doesn't recognise my AngularJS controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ide, webstorm

My app is running without any errors, but WebStorm seems to have problems with the way I use my controllers. I declare and link them in my app.js like so:

```
$routeProvider
.when(...)    // Omitted in sample
.when('/register/', {
    templateUrl: '/app/components/register/register.html',
    controller: 'RegisterController',
    controllerAs: 'registerCtrl'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home/'
});
```

And then call them from my templates like so:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-success': registerCtrl.firstNameValidates()}">
```

But hovering over registerCtrl shows the message: "Unresolved variable or type registerCtrl".

If I declare my controller using the ngController directive, all is well, but declaring them in app.js is standard AngularJS behaviour too, as far as I can tell... Could it be that WebStorm just doesn't go that far in resolving variables? Has any one gotten it to work?

Comment: Same happens with me.